# Issues achieving search filter results via shared scope between controllers

Tags: angularjs

In a nutshell, I am trying to get the text entered in a search field associated with one controller in one view to display the search results in a completely different view associated with a different controller.

https://jsfiddle.net/fk8j8s7z/2/

The results of whatever name you enter in the input field in "FIRST VIEW" needs to be displayed in the "SECOND VIEW" (below it's input field) the same way it would display if you entered in that same name in the input field of the "SECOND VIEW" **(this is the primary goal)**.

Please note that the shared 2 way data-binding between the two input fields IS NOT NECESSARY. I only used it as a experiment/hack/dirty-way to try to achieve what I want because I don't know of any other better way! If any of you can get the primary goal to work WITHOUT the 2 way data-binding between the two input fields that would be most preferred and I would be extremely grateful! Thank you in advance!

HTML/VIEW

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="first">
        <h3>FIRST</h3> begin typing here: Tom, Dick, or Harry
        </br>
       <br/><input type="text" ng-model="data1.text" />
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="second">
    <h3>SECOND</h3> The results of what ever name you enter in the input field in "FIRST VIEW" needs to be displayed below the same way it would display if you entered in that same name in the input field in "SECOND VIEW" (this is the primary goal).

        </br></br>
        <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control"  ng-model="data2.text" ng-change="searchText = data2.text">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:searchText'> {{person.name}} </li>
    </ul>


    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.factory("sharedScope", function($rootScope) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    scope.data = {};
    return scope;
});

app.controller("first", function($scope, sharedScope) {
    $scope.data1 = sharedScope.data;
});

app.controller("second", function($scope, sharedScope) {
    $scope.data2 = sharedScope.data;

    $scope.people = [
        {
            name:'Tom'
        },
        {
            name:'Dick'
        },
        {
            name:'Harry'
        }

    ]
});
```

Comment: Set filter to match `ng-model` .... `filter:data2.text` works fine. Also...no need to create an angular scope in factory. Just return an object

Comment: Did you try changing the `ng-repeat` filter as I showed?

Comment: Perfect it worked! Thank you so much. How do I upvote/ mark your comment as the answer etc you if you care about that?

Comment: Added matching answer. vote/accept controls are on left of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the filter in ng-repeat to match same model object as `ng-model` used on the input

Change

```
<li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:searchText'> {{person.name}} </li>
```

To

```
<li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:data2.text'> {{person.name}} </li>
```